# Chrome extension code which crawls data from a webpage with AngularJS ng-bind fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I need to collect response data of a webpage queried consequtively by different parameter values.
The webpage populates a table cell which I am interested using some AngularJS code, using ng-bind directive.
I control the flow with chrome.tabs.update to refresh the page, and execute background script from the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event.
My code gets  innerText as "" instead of its real value.
I guess the value gets populated by AngularJS, but it needs some time.

I tried to wait for 5 seconds, everything waited including AngularJS. It did not work.
I tried to put my code in document "load" event, but it did not work

### The WebPage with AngularJS

```
<td class="xTt ng-binding" ng-bind="gunlukTahmin[0].enYuksekGun1 | kaliteKontrol">14</td>
```

### payload.js (Chrome Extension)

```
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("xTt ng-binding")[0].innerHTML;

y = ""
```

### popup.js (Chrome Extension)

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (callback) {
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'payload.js', runAt: "document_end"});
});
chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:urlAna });


y = "14"
```

Comment: 1. Where exactly did you wait for 5 seconds? Try wrapping around executeScript like this: setTimeout(() => chrome.tabs.executeScript(......), 5000) 2. the parameter of the listener is `tab` (not `callback`) and you should use it instead of null, specifically `tab.id` 3. the problem may be that the tab is opened in background (not focused) so Angular waits for it to become active. 4. `runAt: "document_end"` makes no difference here because it's even earlier than the default document_idle 5. chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Here are my answers;

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Here are my answers; 1. setTimeout applied successful, but did not solve my problem. 2. corrected 3. it seems on top, except my extensions popup frame. how can I check that? 4. this should be trivial. I need to wait for 5 seconds asynch in payload.js, for the Angularjs populate the data. Send the content as message with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tahminlerMessage);;`   5. deleted